# How are newlibc stubs supposed to be included/linked into one's code

Tags: c, linker, embedded, arm

During my project's linking process the linker fails with the following errors unless I make an explicit call in my code to one of of the stub functions (i.e. _sbrk):

```
c:/toolchains/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\stdlib/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/stdlib/abort.c:63: undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/toolchains/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:61: undefined reference to `_kill'
c:/toolchains/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:96: undefined reference to `_getpid'
c:/toolchains/yagarto/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libg.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
C:\msys\1.0\home\yagarto\newlib-build\arm-none-eabi\newlib\libc\reent/../../../../../newlib-1.19.0/newlib/libc/reent/sbrkr.c:60: undefined reference to `_sbrk'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am aware that I need some stubs functions that newlibc requires and I have a "C" file that contains all of the ones mentioned above as missing and I am also positive that the file is being compiled and added to an archive file (*.a) that is later linked.

I am calling the linker using the following commands

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -L -T linkerscript.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET).map -lc archive.a
```

My question is simple (I hope) How can I make sure that the linker links my stub functions into the elf file without having to make an explicit function call from one of my project files?

Comment: Does link order matter here like building an executable?  Those errors look like the ones I get when I link libraries to an executable in the wrong order.

Comment: @Mosby So far the only way I have found to solve the issue is by calling one of the stub functions explicitly. Changing the link order of my project files seem to have no effect on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those errors you're getting refer to the linker not being able to find the appropriate library. My first suspicion is in how you're using your arguments, specifically your specification of archive directory (-L) and the archive.a file.  I'm thinking it should go like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -L. -T linkerscript.ld -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,$(TARGET).map -lc -larchive
```

where the changes I'd make are:

1. **-L.** means use the current directory to look for library files to link.
2. **-lc** specifies to use the archive file libc.a.
3. **-larchive** specifies to use the archive file libarchive.a.

For more info I'd suggest checking out the[GNU GCC reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options).

Comment: I am going to try your suggestions. In the mean time where did you find that flag **-lc** I have searched the GCC reference but I can't find it there. Even Google hasn't been too helpful in finding where the gcc man page -lc is mentioned

Comment: @Mischief Actually the flag is -l and what I'm assuming is that you have a lib file called libc.a It's not really a change, that was in the command line of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `--verbose` to `gcc` to see exactly where `archive.a` is showing up in the list of libraries and objects passed to the linker.

You need to arrange things so that `archive.a` is searched *after* `libg.a` since that's the archive that contains the objects that end up with undefined references.

You might be able to fix this by adding `-lg` before `archive.a` on the `gcc` command line. 
`-lg` should in `libg.a` earlier than where it's getting pulled in now by default and more importantly pull it in before `archive.a`.